# JavaScript passing string and integer from PHP into function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to pass both a string and an integer into the same function, howe I have issue with quotes.  I figured out that the error is in the `echo $q->info` part, I must use double quotations on this code.

Can someone help me to write this `$q->info`, but to get real value not `$q->info`?

My code so far is

```
<td><a href="javascript:add(<?php echo $q->info?>,<?php echo $q->id?>)">Edit</a></td>
```

and the js function

```
function add(var,var2)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Use _JSON_ as an intermediary. It will save you much headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a PHP variable. To convert it to a string representation of a JavaScript literal, use `json_encode`. To make it safe to insert into an HTML attribute value, use `htmlspecialchars`.

```
<td><a href="javascript:add(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($q->info)); ?>,<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($q->id)); ?>)">Edit</a></td>
```

That said, it would be better to write your code to follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

```
<td>
    <form action="edit" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="info" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($q->info); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($q->id); ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="edit">
    </form>
</td>
```

And then something like:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    add(this.elements.info.value, this.elements.id.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the string.

```
<td><a href="javascript:add('<?php echo $q->info?>',<?php echo $q->id?>)">Edit</a></td>
```

Also, `var` is an invalid variable/argument name (identifier).

Comment: Your attribute now looks like `href="javascript:add("`. That isn't going to work.

Comment: close but not correct this is right code <td><a href='javascript:add(<?php echo $q->id?>,"<?php echo $q->info?>")'>Edit</a></td>

Comment: After editing, that will only work if the string contains no `'` characters, no `"` characters and no new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of your question: Preg replace part of string?

```
echo substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "-DELETED"));
```